# OpenFileDialog() - How to set the MultiSelect option based on the file filter?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

OpenFileDialog() - How to set the MultiSelect option based on the file filter?

My OpenFileDialog can select 2 types of files. This is the Filter used:

"LFA or log files (.lfa, .log)|*.lfa;*.log"

With MultiSelect property set to false.

New requirement change is: User should be allowed to select multiple log files but only one LFA file.

If I set MultiSelect to true, it will allow select multiple log and lfa files.

Please advise is there any way to implement this feature?

Comment: Can you post your code you work so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your answer, if you don't want the UI of the file dialog to close and reopen, you can actually do it. Having your `IsValidFileSelection`, it should be a matter of doing:

```
dlgFileBrowse.FileOk += (s,e) => {
   var dlg = s as OpenFileDialog;
   if (dlg == null) return;
   if (!IsValidFileSelectiom(dlg.FileNames))
   {
      // Or whatever
      MessageBox.Show("Please select one log/lfa file or multiple log files.");
      e.Cancel = true;
   }         
};
```

Before calling `OpenDialog()`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the requirement is handled now.

```
        // Set filter for file extension and default file extension
        dlgFileBrowse.DefaultExt = ".log";
        dlgFileBrowse.Filter = "LFA or log files (.lfa, .log)|*.lfa;*.log";
        dlgFileBrowse.Title = "Select one LFA/Log file or multiple log files.";
        dlgFileBrowse.InitialDirectory = UserSettingsHelper.GetLastBrowsedPath();
       // Allow user to select multiple log files.
        dlgFileBrowse.Multiselect = true;
```

This is how I am calling the OpenBrowse dialog.

```
if (dlgFileBrowse.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Validate the file selection.
            if (IsValidFileSelectiom(dlgFileBrowse.FileNames))
            {
                // Processing my files here.
            }
            else
            {
                // Display selection criterion.
                this.UiMessage = "Please select one log/lfa file or multiple log files.";
            }
        }
```

Where the validation is handled in a separate method as below.

```
public bool IsValidFileSelection(string[] fileNames)
    {
        bool isValid = false;

        // There is no need to check the file types here.
        // As it is been restricted by the openFileBrowse

        if (fileNames != null && fileNames.Count() > 0)
        {
            if (fileNames.Count() == 1) // can be one .lfa file of one .log file
            {
                isValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // If multiple files are there. none shoulf be of type .lfa
                isValid = ! fileNames.Any( f => Path.GetExtension(f) == IntegoConstants.Lfa_Extension);
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    }
```

This involves a round trip to the end user. It would be better, if this validation can be done in the OpenFileDialog. But unfortunately I am not seeing any work around.

Comment: This is possible if you can work with unmanage code. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy) for mor info

Comment: @MaluMN see my updated answer, you can actually do it without having to close and reopen the dialog, using the `FileOk` event

Comment: @Sakura that's way over the top, plus, many dialogs change on different windows versions, so relying on picking the handles is IMHO a bad way to handle it, and could cause problems when the OS changes them